# Page does not redirect when setting window.location in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, window.location

I am trying to redirect the page dynamically depending upon the value of the dropdown box.
I get the value of drop down box in JavaScript. Depending on the dropdown value I want to redirect the page.

This is sample code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function RedirectMe(){
            var chosanDept = document.getElementById("Dept");
            var str = chosanDept.options[chosanDept.selectedIndex].text;
            if(str=='HR')
                { 
                    alert('Yes in IF' + str);
                    window.location = "http://www.google.com";
                }
        }
    </script>
```

here
 `chosanDept` is the variable to get the value of dropdown box. But I am not able to redirect page using various function like 
window.location, location.replace, location.href.
And one more my if condition works, I get the alert 'Yes in IF HR'

What goes wrong here?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?  (F12 in Chrome or IE, Ctrl+Shift+K in Firefox.)

Comment: @RichieHindle, i didn't get any errors in console in both the browser

Comment: Hi Optimus, your code works if you use onChange event on the select element like 
    <select id="Dept" onChange="RedirectMe()">
 <option>select</option>
        <option>HR</option>
    </select>

Comment: @RupamDatta Actually i am submitting the form. So i have added event in the form only as '"onSubmit = "RedirectMe()"'. And all the including select are inside the form only.

Comment: Okay. I tried your code and it worked like a gem. Anyways, great work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding `return false;` to the end of your `RedirectMe()` function

And then wherever you are calling the function, make sure you put `return` there, like `onclick="return RedirectMe();"`

Comment: thanks a lot, adding return false and return RedirectMe() works fine. But i am not getting how it works by adding return?. Because in the standalone application just for redirecting, it works without the return statement.

Comment: @Optimus I believe it is because returning false cancels the submission of your form, which is what you want to do, stop submitting your form and go somewhere else.

Comment: yes, it doesn't submit the form with the return. So is there any other way to achieve this. Form submission and the redirection in the same.

Comment: @Optimus Not as far a I know, I guess if you want to process the form submission and then redirect, you should do the redirect server side.